# Increase or decrease point intervals in high chart

Tags: highcharts

I would like to have specific point intervals in high chart.

I have a passrate chart where in the Y axis shows the percentage passrate. But I would like be able to alter the y axis plot points.

Please refer to this fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/Mn6sB/2/

Here is a small code piece - how ever the range is not 10 intervals.
   yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'PassCount'
                },

```
            min: 0,
            max:100,
            minTickInterval:10
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> minTickInterval: NumberSince 2.3.0
>   The minimum tick interval allowed in axis values. For example on zooming in on an axis with daily data, this can be used to prevent the axis from showing hours.

If you want the y axis tick interval changes when you zoom in, you need to enable the zooming first.

```
chart: {
  renderTo: 'chartContainer',
  type: 'spline',
  zoomType: 'y'
}
```

Or, if you want to fix the tick interval, what you need is not [minTickInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.minTickInterval) but [tickInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickInterval)

So your small code piece should be:

```
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max:100,
    tickInterval:10
}
```